# how to access the object for a class in some other page?

Tags: java, jsp, jquery

i have create a object for hashmap with some keys, values in one.jsp, now i want to use the same object in two.jsp. how to send this object to two.jsp , and how can i accessess the data ( keys, values) in two.jsp.

**EDITED:**

**one.jsp**

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();
map.add( new Integer( 2 ), "two" );
map.add( new Integer( 4 ), "four" );
System.out.println( map );
// sending param to two.jsp
session.setAttribute("value",map);
```

**two.jsp**

```
   // how can i access that object "map" here ?
       String map=session.getAttribute("value"); // error
```

**error**

```
 error :object cant be assign to string –
```

**solved**

```
 HashMap s_hm=(HashMap)session.getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: friend please format the code properly

Comment: use jsp:Bean to pass from one jsp to another or if you forward from the first jsp then you can just add parameters to your request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put the values in session and can retrieve the same throughout the session
for keeping the session try this way

```
session.setAttribute("value",map);
```

and to retrive it use

```
session.getAttribute("value");
```

This is the demo code for keeping values in session.
The following code will put values in session

```
<%@ page import="java.util.HashMap"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%session.setAttribute("hi","hi");

Map map = new HashMap();
map.put( new Integer( 2 ), "two" );
map.put( new Integer( 4 ), "four" );
//System.out.println( map );
// sending param to two.jsp
session.setAttribute("value",map);%>
```

The following code will retrive value from the session as well display on the browser

```
<%out.println(session.getAttribute("value"));%>
```

**output on the browser**

```
{2=two, 4=four}
```

Comment: It base on requirement whether it is session or request.....here request is appriopriate :)

Comment: @ShoaibChikate i am telling OP that this is one of the way.Session is maintained in web apps,so keep the value in session itself

Comment: But if you see that storing variable in session is not much recommended...as it is important object...end of day every thing based on requirement ...and i m not telling u r wrong bro

Comment: see i am unable access that object in two.jsp.its giving error . i have updated the code see once. thanks bro.

Comment: @user2773010 cast it into string like (String)session.getAttribute("value");

Comment: @user2773010 please see my updated answer.If you face any problem then feel free to ask

Comment: @user2773010 accepting answer is the stackoverflow way of saying thank you

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your need, you can add it to the `request`/`session` as an attribute before forwarding it to the second jsp:

```
request.setAttribute("transferMap",map );
```

`transferMap` is the name of the attribute and `map` is the actual map.

Answer (score 0):

Use a servlet to set an attribute instead of a one.jsp

```
request.setAttribute("hashMap",map );
//Forward the request to two.jsp using Request Dispatcher
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/two.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Then use jstl in your **two.jsp** to retrieve it.

```
<c:out value="${hashMap[2]}"/>
<c:out value="${hashMap[4]}"/>
```

You need to include jstl jars in your project and include this line in your jsp.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```